# EWS Extended Properties to Microsoft Graph Extended Properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-calendar

Can someone tell me how to convert the EWS Extended Property to Microsoft Graph Extended Property Definiton because I can't access the single value extended properties of the appointments that are created with EWS.
When i create an appointment through the Graph API i am able to access the defined property.

This is my EWS property definition:

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition myPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, 1001, MapiPropertyType.String);
```

I have tried the following variants but none of them is working for me. I don't receive a single value extended properties array.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq 'String 1001')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq 'String 0x3E9')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq 'Integer 1001')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq 'Integer 0x3E9')
```

I searched for common problems, but none of them helped me.
Any ideas will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example you need to include the GUID for Public String so it should look like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id eq 'Integer {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x3E90'))
```

However you named property definition doesn't look correct if you for named properties using lid value the range should be 0x8000 and 0x8FFF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-pst/60003704-dfa6-476f-b782-ce8bb52a2df3

That property range your trying to use is reserved and I'm surprised it does work if your using PublicStrings probably using a unique string as the property Id would be a better idea.

Comment: I didn't realise that i had to set the namespace of the PublicStrings. It was a liitle difficult for me to realise how it is constructed, but i think i got it. Then I just had to replace Integer with String and 0x3E9 was the right hex for me. 
Thanks for the help!